# Can お前 be used as a polite substitute of あなた?

Tags: meaning

So, I know that お前 nowadays is used as a rude way of saying "you". However, during one of my readings, I came across a strange use of お前 which, from the context, won't really make any sense if it was meant to be rude.

Basically, this is a "noblewoman" talking to her servants : she used お前たち although she spoke with them in a rather friendly way, always using polite forms such as ～です or ～ます.

Could I have more information about this お前 ?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Maybe post a short passage from which the quote is taken?

Comment: Are you asking if there *was* such a usage or if there *is* such a usage available in regular speech now?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't. お前 is a rude way of saying "you", even if she always uses polite forms such as ～です or ～ます. Probably she didn't use the word except to her servants , right?

The author may want to contrast polite forms with a rude way of speaking and expect that the readers will be a bit surprised to hear it just like you were.

Addition: お前 was used as a respect way of saying "you" till about 400 years ago, but it doesn't be used like that now. This is the source. http://gogen-allguide.com/o/omae.html

Comment: でも、何か質問者はこのふう（https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1075957545）の時代劇の使い方について、聞かれていることではないか。

Comment: Thank you for your teaching and correction. I added the information.

Comment: 古語を持ち出さなくても、部下や仲間に対して「お前たちは下がっていなさい！私が参ります！」「お前たちも苦労しているのですね…」といった喋り方をする高貴な女性は普通にいると思います。少なくともフィクションでは。

Comment: Yes, I imagined that. I imagined  impertinent young madams in fiction.

Answer (score 2):

お前 is clearly rude only when its used to address your boss, a stranger, etc. It's a very common friendly second-person pronoun among close friends, especially young male friends.

Being able to use お前 is often the sign of friendliness, frankness or a good vertical relationship. There is nothing wrong if you used お前 to your children, servant, etc., although it sounds more or less "bossy" or paternalistic. I imagine how this noblewoman can feel at ease with the servants.

Comment: For example [Lunafreya](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Lunafreya_Nox_Fleuret) from FFXV may as well address her people with お前たち while sticking to ～です/～ます style at the same time. (although my memory is already vague)